# Logs and percentage change in equation

Tags: microeconomics, economic-growth

Suppose I have the following relationship between output $y$, capital stock $k$ and total factor productivity $tfp$,

$$\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial k}{\partial tfp}*\frac{\partial tfp}{\partial t}$$

Then taking the logs,

$$ln\bigg(\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}\bigg)=ln\bigg(\frac{\partial k}{\partial tfp}*\frac{\partial tfp}{\partial t}\bigg)$$

$$ \iff \%\Delta y= \%\Delta k_{tfp}+\%\Delta tfp_t$$

Where the last equation is the percentage change in $y$ as the sum of the elasticity of $k$ to $tfp$ and the change in $tfp$ over time. Am I evaluating these logs correctly?

Comment: What do you denote by $t$?

Comment: @denesp t is time